# Is it possible to just get the domain and TLD from an NSURL? No www or anything else?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

Say I have `http://www.youtube.com`, `http://youtube.com`, and `https://www1.youtube.com/moretext`. How would I write a check to see if all of those URLs are from youtube.com?

I tried `url.host` and it seems to keep the `www.` and whatnot, which is not what I want.

I basically just want to be able to say:

```
if ([url isFromWebsite:@"youtube.com"]) {
    // Do things.
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Take `url.host`, call [`-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:) on it, and look at the last two elements of the array.

Comment: @bdesham You should make this an answer.

Comment: @JesseRusak even your code will fail for youtube.commydomain.com! Further it will be having more string manipulations, first to extract url.host, then to have arrays and then actually check 2 elements that too hard codedly last two.

Comment: @GauravGoyal I'm not sure you mean by "my code", but I think that a couple of string manipulations are likely to be pretty irrelevant unless this function is being called thousands of times.

Comment: @bdesham YouTube.co.uk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s an untested category on `NSURL` that will provide the method you want.

```
@implementation NSURL (IsFromWebsite)

- (BOOL) isFromWebsite:(NSString *)domain
{
    NSArray *selfHostComponents = [[self host] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSArray *targetHostComponents = [domain componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    NSInteger selfComponentsCount = [selfHostComponents count];
    NSInteger targetComponentsCount = [targetHostComponents count];
    NSInteger offset = selfComponentsCount - targetComponentsCount;

    if (offset < 0)
        return NO;

    for (NSUInteger i = offset; i < selfComponentsCount; i++) {
        if (![selfHostComponents[i] isEqualToString:targetHostComponents[i - offset]])
            return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

@end
```

**Edit:** Another (also untested) way to do the same thing, as suggested by Jesse Rusak:

```
@implementation NSURL (IsFromWebsite)

- (BOOL) isFromWebsite:(NSString *)domain
{
    NSArray *selfComponents = [[self host] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSArray *targetComponents = [domain componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSInteger sizeDifference = [selfComponents count] - [targetComponents count];

    if (sizeDifference < 0)
        return NO;

    return [[selfComponents subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(sizeDifference, [targetComponents count])]
            isEqualToArray:targetComponents];
}

@end
```

Comment: It would be easier just to take a sub-array of targetComponentsCount size from selfHostComponents and check isEqual: with targetHostComponents.

Comment: @JesseRusak Good idea. I went ahead and added such a version to my answer.

Comment: This looks solid.  One thought: you may want to consider making the compare case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

`NSURL` — and indeed URLs in general — doesn't care too much about the actual content of the host portion of the URL; that's up to clients to interpret and handle. So it's up to you to perform your own handling of this info.

Here's a nice simple way:

```
- (BOOL)isYouTubeURL:(NSURL *)url;
{
    NSString *host = url.host;

    // Test the simple case of the domain being a direct match
    // Case-insensitive, as domain names are defined to be
    if ([host caseInsensitiveCompare:@"youtube.com"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        return YES;
    }

    // And now the more complex case of a subdomain
    // Look back from just the end of the string
    NSStringCompareOptions options = NSBackwardsSearch|NSAnchoredSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch;
    NSRange range = [host rangeOfString:@".youtube.com" options:options];
    return (range.location != NSNotFound);
}
```

You could optimise this if needed by searching only for the domain, and then seeing if the previous character doesn't exist (case #1 above), or has a `.` before it (case #2 above). Going even further, `CFURL` has API to tell you where in the raw string the host lies, and could search directly through that.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs [bdesham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371228/bdesham)'s answer in Swift 3.

```
extension URL {
    func isFromWebsite(domain: String) -> Bool {
        var selfHostComponents = self.host!.components(separatedBy: ".")
        var targetHostComponents = domain.components(separatedBy: ".")
        let selfComponentsCount = selfHostComponents.count
        let targetComponentsCount = targetHostComponents.count
        let offset = selfComponentsCount - targetComponentsCount
        if offset < 0 {
            return false
        }
        for i in offset..<selfComponentsCount {
            if !(selfHostComponents[i] == targetHostComponents[i - offset]) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use the following code as NSString category

```
- (BOOL)isFromWebsite: (NSString *)website {
     NSRange searchResult = [self rangeOfString:website];
     if (searchResult.location != NSNotFound) {
         return YES;
     }
     return NO;
}
```

You can use case insensitive compare also if that is a use case.
Hope this helps.

Comment: That will also match `youtube.commydomain.com`, which is perhaps not desired.

Comment: According to me this is the most optimized solution in real world scenarios.

Comment: -1 because in the context of comparing domain names, sloppy “optimizations” like this can lead to giant security holes.

Comment: Exactly, this could cause a big security issue with my application, so it's incredibly dangerous.