# How can I get just the TLD of an NSURL?

Tags: ios, nsurl

For example:

"http://www.youtube.com" --> ".com"

"http://www.google.com.gr" --> ".com.gr"

"[https://made.in.china.chinesewebsite.닷컴](https://made.in.china.chinesewebsite.%EB%8B%B7%EC%BB%B4)" --> ".닷컴"

The host of a URL is a dead-end.

```
NSURL *URL;

[URL host];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430620/is-it-possible-to-just-get-the-domain-and-tld-from-an-nsurl-no-www-or-anything

Comment: The answer takes for granted that you know what you are looking for and it implements a comparison. It works for this [URL isFromWebsite:"youtube.com"] as well as this [URL isFromWebsite:".com"];

Comment: But `.com.gr` is not the TLD-- `.gr` is.

Comment: Yes, technically you are right as much as Duncan C is but the SLDs  "youtube.co.uk"  and "youtube.com" do not have the same value when you are trying to figure out the root of a website that "youtube". Things are messed up.

Comment: That's the problem though-- everything after the TLD is subject to local variations. There's `.com.gr` but `.co.uk`. Every TLD gets to decide their own rules for what happens after the TLD. Every one is a special case.

Answer (score 1):

Get the host of the url, break it up at the `.` delimiter, and take the last component.

```
- (NSString *) tldOfURL: NSURL *theURL; {
  NSString *host = theURL.host;
  NSArray *parts = [host componentsSeparatedByString: @"."];
  if parts.count < 2 {
    return nil;
  }
  return parts.lastObject;
}
```

At first my answer was to use `NSURLComponents`, as in most cases that class does all the heavy lifting for you, but it looks like it doesn't have a mechanism for extracting the TLD.

Note that the above will return nil if the host name does not contain at least one period (`.`) and will return an empty string if the host ends with a period. Both of these cases should be treated as errors.

P.S. I'm starting to get rusty at Objective-C syntax. Hard to believe, given how many years I's spent writing Objective-C!

Comment: This will not work for ".com.gr" or any other TLD that is made up by more than one component separated by a dot. P.S. Your name sounds familiar. :)